# PySpark reference to self inside map() and reduce() functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508685/pyspark-serializing-the-self-referenced-object-in-map-lambdas) question, I should avoid calling self inside a map function. Extending this, I have two questions:
Let's use the same code stated there:

```
class C0(object):

  def func0(self, arg): # added self
    ...

  def func1(self, rdd): # added self
    func = self.func0
    result = rdd.map(lambda x: func(x))
```

1. Is `result = rdd.map(lambda x:func(x))` the same thing as

   `result = rdd.map(func)`? Specially in this situation where I use `func = self.func0` before?
2. Let's say func0 calls another method from the class:

class C0(object):

```
  def func2(self, arg):
    ...

  def func0(self, arg): # added self
    self.func2(arg)
    ...

  def func1(self, rdd): # added self
    func = self.func0
    result = rdd.map(lambda x: func(x))
```

How does Spark handle this? Should I do `func2 = self.func2` inside func0?

Comment: [You should use `staticmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32505426)

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much